# How to get and set elements in nested list

Tags: r, list, nested

lets assume i have the following structure:

**R-Code**

```
listAll = list()
list3 = list(id=14,attr1 = '',attr2='n4',attr3=list(text1='tx1',text2=''))
list4 = list(id=15,attr1 = '',attr2='n1',attr3=list(text1='tx1',text2=''))
listAll = append(listAll,list(values=list3))
listAll = append(listAll,list(values=list4))
str(listAll)

#result

List of 2
$ values:List of 4
..$ id   : num 14
..$ attr1: chr ""
..$ attr2: chr "n4"
..$ attr3:List of 2
.. ..$ text1: chr "tx1"
.. ..$ text2: chr ""
$ values:List of 4
..$ id   : num 15
..$ attr1: chr ""
..$ attr2: chr "n1"
..$ attr3:List of 2
.. ..$ text1: chr "tx1"
.. ..$ text2: chr ""
```

How can i set/get for example the attr2 which belongs to id 14?

I thought this can't be difficult... all i have to do would be (for get):

1. Get Index of searched id
2. get list corresponding to this index
3. get value with $attr1 on the list from step two

Unfortunately i dont know how to get point one done.

Assumed i have the id = 14 and the corresponding index 1..the next steps will be (two and three together):

```
listAll[[1]]$attr2 #results "n4"
```

So the question is how to get the index (in this example = 1) matching the id = 14.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using `sapply`

```
##  sapply(listAll, "[[", "id")
## werte werte 
##    14    15
```

Then you can apply `which` to get the index like this

```
which(sapply(listAll, "[[", "id") == 14)
## werte   
##     1 

which(sapply(listAll, "[[", "id") == 15)
## werte 
##     2
```